# Is there an elegant Ruby method to loop through array from specific element with access to respective index?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, indexing

I want to start any where in an array (for example) the last two elements in `arr` and access the elements as well as their respective indexes `1,2`.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? 

Without using a the standard method (below) with an index variable `i` and `while`.

```
  arr = [82,217,170]
  i = 3

    while i < arr.length
      puts "#{arr[i]}" + " " + "#{i}"        
    end
```

Other loop methods can begin at a specific element but return a new array. 

I cannot print the elements' respective indexes because its now referring to the new array.

```
  arr = [82,217,170]

  arr.drop(1).each_with_index do |item,index|
    puts "#{item}" + " " + "#{index}"
  end

  arr[1..2].each_with_index do |item,index|
    puts "#{item}" + " " + "#{index}"
  end
```

Output:

```
217 0 <== should be 1
170 1 <== should be 2
217 0 <== should be 1
170 1 <== should be 2
```

Reason for question and Uses:

This would be useful if you want to have nested loops in a function that already has a lot of code. You don't have to instantiate multiple index variables outside of each loop.

Comment: This for nested loops sounds like you maybe should use [#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) instead...

Answer (score 1):

If you reverse the positions of your `drop` and `each_with_index` calls, you'd have:

```
arr.each_with_index.drop(1).each { |e, i| puts "#{e} #{i}" }
# 217 1
# 170 2
```

You could also `zip` in your indices:

```
arr.zip(0 .. arr.length-1).drop(1).each { |e, i| puts "#{e} #{i}" }
```

but there's not much point to that extra complexity. Or you could say this and get right to the point:

```
(1 .. arr.length-1).each { |i| puts "#{arr[i]} #{i}" }
```

but that might qualify as a "loop with an index variable".

Comment: `arr.each_with_index` does this piece of code return an array?

Comment: No, it gives you an `Enumerator`. But `arr.each_with_index.drop(1)` leaves you with an `Array`.

Comment: The last solution seems the best for my case. I don't mean to avoid all index variables. I am just avoiding variables instantiated outside of the loop and incremented... such as ones in the case of while loops

Comment: Right, thanks. How embarrassing. You could use `(1 ... arr.length)` (not the three dots) too but I don't see that many three-dot ranges.

Comment: mu, I wanted to commend you for using `1 .. arr.length-1` rather than `1 ... arr.length`, but from your comment I’m not sure it was intentional. It seems to me that always using two dots will result in fewer bugs than using two here, three there. I’m a two-dot-only coder.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, the `..` was intentional, the missing `- 1` was not. I don't think I've ever used `...` in real life, too visually confusing.

Answer (score 1):

`each_with_index` does not take a parameter to specify the starting index; `with_index` does. Its a method from Enumerator, so let's create one with `each`.

```
arr = [82,217,170]
start_at = 1

arr[start_at..-1].each.with_index(start_at){|item,i|puts "#{item} #{i}"}

# 217 1
# 170 2
```